# Searching within objects inside mongo collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm playing around with MongoDB with mongoose and come to a slight roadblock atm trying to implement searching within objects in a collection.

So I have a schema that is as follows:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  form_id: Number,
  author: Number,
  data: String,
  files: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

The `data` is just a JSON object of key/values.

An example entry of a record:

```
{
 "form_id" : 5, 
 "author" : 1,
 "data" : "
   {\"staff\":\"Joe Blow\", \"date\":\"25th Jan 2013\"}", 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5101fd4ee6ca550000000003"),
 "date" : ISODate("2013-01-25T03:34:38.377Z"),
 "__v" : 0
}
```

How do I search for a specific value inside the data object? I'm trying to do something like the following but not having any luck :(

```
db.forms.find({form_id: 5, data: '/Joe/i'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the single quotes around the regular expression it should work:

```
db.forms.find({form_id: 5, data: /Joe/i});
```

But are you sure you want `data` to contain a JSON string instead of an object?  An object would give you so much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this?

```
db.forms.find({form_id: 5, "data.staff": /Joe/i});
```

if your 'data' property of forms is an object. and it's way better.